# Time interval quantized?

Tags: capacitor, discharge, time

We have a capacitor fully charged with some voltage. At t=0 we can find the current.

This current will change the voltage of the capacitor. However the information of the change of the voltage of the capacitor will travel at the speed of light in the dialetric material.

So for t<d/c where d is the distance of the mettalic plates and c is the speed of light in the dialetric material the electrons won't feel the change in voltage. After that time interval the information of  change of the electric field will reach the electrons.

The graph of current with respect to time while discharging a capacitor is continuous while from the above reasoning it should be quantized.

Any help?

Comment: You should remember that current is also quantized...it is not continuous. Think about what happens as a single electron moves. However, for most of us on this site the current is effectively continuous so we don't worry about such things.

Comment: So the graph we normally see is a very good approximation to the actual behavior because the time intervals of the travel of the change of information is very small. However if we consider the distance between the plates to be 1 light seconds then it is not that precise

Comment: Very, very few of us worry about the behavior of capacitors with dimensions on the order of a light second. You might do better asking this in the physics.SE site.

Comment: Yes but this can solve problems with infinities. For Dt =0 and a change in current the back emf from electromagnetic induction will be infinite.

Comment: *"from the above reasoning it should be quantized"*. In your reasoning, you have only described a time delay = *d/c*. It doesn't imply quantisation. A related concept is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Current in a capacitor is not quantized in units of e. That's why capacitors do not have Poisson noise.

Answer (score 3):

We deal with time-of-flight issues in large components by making them up of transmission lines, and then seeing what happens when we launch steps into them.

It is certainly the case that if we take a length of open circuit transmission line, and apply a current step to one end, then the voltage will immediately jump to Z0.I, where Z0 is the line impedance, while a voltage wave and current wave get launched into the line.

These waves travel the length of the line. Finding an open circuit that can't support a current, they get reflected with the current in antiphase, the voltage in phase, with the voltage at the far end rising to 2Z0.I.

These reflected waves eventually reach the sending end. A current source is an open circuit, so the same sort of reflection happens, and a voltage and current now wave head off down the line again. The sending end rises to a voltage of 3Z0.I.

This continues indefinitely. You can see how we can derive the capacitive behaviour of an open circuit line, as the voltage is rising by a step of Z0.I per transit of the line length, that is, linearly in time due to the continuous inflow of current.

In practice, the transmission line making a capacitor will not be lossless, and the shape tends to be two dimensional. The first tends to smear out the steps, the second overlays small steps at multiple delays, tending to smear out the steps. Along with the very small time scale for practical capacitors, this means the stepped voltage response is rarely seen in practice, and rarely troubles circuit designers.

In the specific case of good quality one dimensional transmission line like coax, or microstrip on PCB, this stepped response is very visible. We can make pulse-forming networks from lengths of transmission line, and have to be careful with long PCB traces that we can drive logic gate inputs to clean levels.

Answer (score 0):

> the information of the change of the voltage of the capacitor will travel at the speed of light in the dialetric material.

Indeed, and in fact, at this level of detail, the change in charge/current/voltage across each plate of the capacitor propagates at a finite speed as well.

If you really want to ponder the minutiae at this level, you're going to have to model ALL of the physical details of the capacitor, using a full-blown field solver.